# executable jars with timers

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, timer

I wrote a program with two timers running small animations. Originally timerX was running at 5ms and timerY was running a 1ms. I exported the program to an executable jar file and everything worked fine. I then sent the jar to another computer running the same specs and again there were no problems. However, I decided to speed up timerX, so I changed this timer to run at 1ms, ran, saved and exported the file. From my desktop this new file ran perfectly but when passing it to the other computer there was no change from the previous one. Is there something I need to do in eclipse before I resend it to the executable jar file? Also why is it running fine from my desktop but not on the other computer - the second timer which is also set at 1ms runs equally fast in both instances.

Answer (score 2):

As shown in [*Timer accuracy*](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/time.html#ACCURACY), clock resolution depends on the host platform and operating system. Although [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) will *coalesce* events by default, the timer thread will tend to saturate quickly with such a short period (high frequency). You may need to compensate on older systems.

Comment: I appreciate this and expected a difference - but what seems to be happening is that is has somehow locked into the first settings I originally made (Timer 5) - even if i change my code to Timer 100 for example and save it to a jar when i send this to my other computer it still seems to be running at timer 5 speed - therefore I cant compensate to go slower or quicker.

Comment: If the value is a [compile-time constant](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/constant.html), you may need to do a clean and build to refresh the corresponding class file.